# C array segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, segmentation-fault

Sometimes you will not get a runtime error when you access your array out of range in C code. such as:

```
char array[1024];
char* ptr = array;
*(ptr-10) = 'a';

//or

*(ptr-4096) = 'a';
```

Assuming the `array` is on the stack, I am curious about what is the MIN **SIZE** that will let `*(ptr-SIZE) = 'a'` throw a segmentation fault in any situation?

for example:

```
*(ptr-4096*1024) = 'a' // this will always throw a segmentation fault
*(ptr-4096*8) = 'a' // sometimes this will not throw a segmentation fault
```

**2017/1/10, new added:**

I feel sorry for not stating the question clearly. : (

What I want to know is not just a ambiguous **UNDEFINED**. Assuming the stack is high, and heap is low. So the memory layout will be:

```
high *********
     * stack *  <-  my array goes here
     *********
     *       *
     *       *  <-  ptr may be here
     *       *
     *********
     * heap  *
     *********
     * ???   *  <- ptr may be here
     *********
```

Of course I know that

> The problem is that C/C++ doesn't actually do any boundary checking with regards to arrays. It depends on the OS to ensure that you are accessing valid memory

So, the code above will cause the OS kernel invoke `do_page_fault`, and will try to find `vma` of the address, and check if the `vma->vm_start < address`.

Now, let's come back to the question I asked: the **MIN SIZE** that will let `*(ptr-SIZE) = 'a'` throw a segmentation fault **in any situation**. In other word, I want to know the **SIZE** that the `do_page_fault` can afford. It is nothing about the C compiler, but how your OS protects your memory.

Comment: Accessing an array out of bounds is [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: What about the word "undefined" like in "undefined behaviour" is unclear? Where did you hear/read/.. there is a requirement for such an access to generate any specific behaviour?

Comment: You'd be better off re-asking this as an OS question, "what must a userspace process do to trigger a segmentation fault?" rather than what appears to be a newbie C programming question long since answered.

Answer (score 4):

A C standard compliant compiler reserves the right to do *anything* if you index `array[i]` where `i` is less than 0 or greater than 1023.

The behaviour in such cases is said to be *undefined*.

Attempting to second-guess what will happen is futile. But you could always check the generated assembly if you're curious.

Comment: Note that the reference in OP's question is the result of pointer arithmetic, in which case it  _is_  allowed to make a pointer point to `ptr + 1024`, but not to `ptr - 1`. `*(ptr + 1024)` is of course UB.